# Momentjs - Como somar/subtrair datetime?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Segue código:

```
var value = '/Date(1533227866063)/';
var utc = moment().utcOffset() / 60; // -180 / 60 = -3
var datetime_utc = moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"); // 02/08/2018 13:37
var convertDatetime = ??? // 02/08/2018 10:37
```

Tentei com o código a seguir e resultado é o mesmo da variável `datetime_utc`:

```
var convertDatetime = moment(datetime).utcOffset(utc);
```

Veja documentação: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/

Na variável `utc`, ele pode estar com número negativo ou positivo.

Comment: Você tem o resultado de value 02/08/2018 13:37 e deseja que o resultado seja 02/08/2018 10:37, você quer tirar 3 horas da primeira data?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que ser passado no `subtract` uma duração correspondente que no seu caso é `03:00:00` (3 horas) com o comando `moment.duration`, ***exemplo***:

```js
var value = '/Date(1533227866063)/';

var datetime0 = moment(value)
console.log(datetime0.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));    

var time = moment.duration("03:00:00");
var datetime1 = moment(value);
datetime1.subtract(time);
console.log(datetime1.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Também pode ser passado por uma configuração direta no `subtract` um `{h:3}` que é a quantidade de horas, exemplo:

```js
var value = '/Date(1533227866063)/';

var datetime0 = moment(value)
console.log(datetime0.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));    

var datetime1 = moment(value);
datetime1.subtract({h:3});
console.log(datetime1.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

esse sendo bem direta ao que precisa para subtrair.

Outra forma também é utilizando os dois parâmetros exemplo:

```js
var value = '/Date(1533227866063)/';

var datetime0 = moment(value)
console.log(datetime0.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));    

var time = moment.duration("03:00:00");
var datetime1 = moment(value);
datetime1.subtract(3, 'hours');
console.log(datetime1.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Para adicionar só muda o metodo mas, a forma é a mesma exemplo:

```js
var value = '/Date(1533227866063)/';

var datetime0 = moment(value)
console.log(datetime0.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));    

var time = moment.duration("03:00:00");
var datetime1 = moment(value);
datetime1.add(3, 'hours');
console.log(datetime1.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Essas são as formas possíveis para adicionar/subtrair com [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

A sua documentação tem tudo isso explicado

```
moment().add(Number, String);
moment().add(Duration);
moment().add(Object);
```

---

```
moment().subtract(Number, String);
moment().subtract(Duration);
moment().subtract(Object);
```

sendo a explicação dos parâmetros da seguinte forma:

```
|---------------|-------------|
| Key           | Shorthand   |
|---------------|-------------|
| years         | y           |
| quarters      | Q           |
| months        | M           |
| weeks         | w           |
| days          | d           |
| hours         | h           |
| minutes       | m           |   
| seconds       | s           |
| milliseconds  | ms          |
|---------------|-------------|
```

<sub>***Exemplos:***</sub>

```
moment().add(7, 'days').add(1, 'months'); 
moment().add({days:7,months:1});
```

<sub>***Exemplos e documentação em:***</sub>

- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/
- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

Answer (score 0):

Qual resultado pretendes ao certo?

Tens o [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) e o [subtract](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/), que podes usar para adicionar ou remover segundos, minutos, horas etc.

```
var convertDatetime = moment(datetime).add(1, 'days');
```

Se queres converter para UTC, podes usar a função [utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)

```
var convertDatetime = moment.parseZone('2016-05-03T22:15:01+02:00').utc().format(); //"2016-05-03T20:15:01Z"
```

Podes usar a funcao `utcOffset()` sobre um moment gerado usando o teu timestamp para especificares o offset.

```
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
var convertDatetime = moment(datetime).utcOffset(offset);
```

Comment: Tentei a função `zone()` o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: O resultado que eu quero é: `02/08/2018 10:37`.

Comment: Segundo a documentação: This function has been deprecated in 2.9.0. Consider moment.fn.utcOffset instead.

Comment: Não usar a função `zone()`

Comment: Veja essa: http://jsfiddle.net/9PAFg/2799/

Comment: A data e mês inverteu.

Comment: Me parece que é para converter "02/08/2018 13:37 " para timestamp, para fazer ela funcionar.

Comment: Por vezes pode acontecer essa confusao com o dia/mes trocarem, dependendo do que o moment() entende da string que lhe passas, mas podes especificar qual o formato de input passando o formato em que está como 2o parametro. `var convertDatetime = moment('02/08/2018 15:36', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').utcOffset(offset).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");`

Comment: Bora limpar comentário ?